# Q: Android Dev - Background Timer that completes an action when it expires?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, broadcastreceiver

Quick and to the point:
My Activity has a Button, and an EditText to enter a value which represents minutes.. When pressed, I want to close the Activity window, and then in the Background I want to run a countdown Timer, which (after the amount of time the user enters in the EditText is up) perform an action when the time runs out..
ex: They enter "5" and press OK.. The Activity disappears, and 5 minutes later, another Activity pops up..

QUESTION:
What is the best way to do this? (some kind of Receiver? ooor a Service? do I need to run a Handler, or a Thread to do this? Or maybe the Alarm Manager? Or a TimerTask sounded correct, but I've read using timertask is bad for some reason?).. So what would the best practice be here?

Greatly appreciate any guidance!

PS.. Here's what I had for the OK button's code, previously.. It worked a few times, but then suddenly one day stopped working:

```
public void popup_ok(View v) {

    Log.i(TAG, "[popup_ok Button-Click Receipt]");

    EditText et_timer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_timer);

    assert et_timer != null;
    int i = Integer.parseInt(et_timer.getText().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Timer has been set!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    // Close Activity Window after the Timer has been Set
    finish();



// End of "popup_ok" Button Code
}
```

Again, this is what previously worked, but then suddenly broke somehow.. I'm not sure that this was even the proper way to do it in the first place, but it's what I ended up with. Any thoughts?

Thanks again for any further input! I'm a social learner, not a robot ;)

Comment: Take a look on AlarmManager - https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

Use service to run in background as timer will not run if your activity is not in foreground. You can use it with `Alarm-Manager` to run it at set interval or so. One simple implementation inside your service could be

```
void setAlarm(){
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, getClass());

        i.putExtra(Artoo.TIMER, period);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, timeNow + period,
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my Edit to my original post.. Does that look off to you?

Comment: where is your receiver class??

Comment: Anyways basically if you want to run some periodic task, you should separate  it from UI components(Activity, Fragments) and run it in service because Service has it's own lyfecycle.

Comment: So from what I understand, after the user enters the amount of time in the box and pressed the OK button, It should start a Service which contains an AlarmManager object, is this correct? I've been reading some other threads, and it seems most of them suggest using a TimerTask object with a Service.. So which is oorrect - either using the AlarmManager with Service, a TimerTask with Service, or an AlarmManager with a Receiver like I posted in my Code above? Again, I want it to continue the countdown regardless of weather or not the screen is on, etc.. What is the correct one

Comment: Yes after user gives input for alarm, start a service and use alarm manager to notify after given time. Don't use timertask it will not run if your app is not in foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far.. So from what I can tell based on the code you provided, you simply switched in a Service for the PendingIntent rather than a BroadcastReceiver like I had in my Code above.. But I'm left slightly confused as to where I will be getting the User's Input from? I'm still a bit of a newbie, but very eager to learn, and making progress, so I appreciate the time you've taken to assist me. Also, does the Code you provided go inside the Button, and then after the amount of time the user sets, continue my code within the Service? Or is that wrong?

Comment: Take user input from activity/fragment and then start service.